# Docker: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, azure, docker

import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

I'm using Docker to serve a django app. Using Python3 and tried everything but the container is still not working.

-Tried installing:
pip install pymysql
pip install mysql
pip install mysql-connector
pip install msqlclient

-Added these two lines:
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

to manage.py, **init**.py and wsgi.py

Also installed libmysqlclient-dev

The app is up and running in my local env, but when I push a container image the app won't start. I'm pretty sure that "pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()" should do the trick, but for some reasons it is not getting executed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please ensure your requirements.txt file is properly formatted with the correct name for `mysql-python`.

Comment: This topic can be useful for you:
[Azure App Service ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917000/azure-app-service-importerror-libmysqlclient-so-18-cannot-open-shared-object-f)