# Azure App Service ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

On App Azure Linux with Python, the Mysql module seem not work :

```
2018-12-24T19:11:38.215760010Z     import _mysql
2018-12-24T19:11:38.215763810Z ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot 
                               open shared object file: No such file or directory
...
2018-12-24T19:11:27.536810347Z django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
                               Error loading MySQLdb module.
2018-12-24T19:11:27.536813747Z Did you install mysqlclient?
```

requirement :

```
django
mysqlclient
```

Has anyone ever managed to run django on azure web app?

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error.  Using `mysqlclient` also requires native dependencies to be installed:  either the mysql client or the mysql-compatible mariadb client.  In order to address these issues the easiest way, change your project to use `mysql-connector-python` instead of `mysqlclient`.  You will also have to update your settings so that any database engine that uses `django.db.backends.mysql` should be updated to `mysql.connector.django`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is not mysql native client library installed in your Azure App for Linux.

Here is two cases for building custom image.

- For Debian or Ubuntu image, please run `apt install libmysqlclient-dev` firstly to preinstall `libmysqlclient.so` on your Docker image.
- For Fedora or CentOS iamge, please run `yum install mysql-libs` firstly to preinstall the same one.

Or you can directly use the existing image which has preinstalled these required libs from Azure Container Registry or DockerHub.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a try that go to the app service scm site, and find the pip location, then use pip to install the required module.